# multilevel corresponding dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

i have a table with columns id, stud_id, stud_name, stud_email, marks. I want a form with 3 drop-down stud_id, stud_name, stud_email. if anyone select any one of the drop-down the others should fill automatically according to the selected field from database. Thanks in Advance.

i want something like this but with a single table 
 http://www.91weblessons.com/codeigniter-ajax-country-state-city-drop-down/

Comment: you need to send ajax call for that. Get the value of first drop down, send it in ajax call, return with the view of second drop down, and upon selection of second drop down, repeat it again. you can create a dynamic function or you can create different functions for ajax calls it depends on your own programming method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't post any specifics so my answer can only be general, but so I'll just give you the logical flow of the process:

1. Javascript that watches the dropdowns for changes. If you have 3 dropdowns, you'll have to watch the first two.  If you use jquery, it'll be something like:  `$('first_dropdown').change({//your ajax call goes here})`
2. Your ajax call. From inside the watch function mentioned above, create an ajax script that calls a php function that gets the data you want to populate the next dropdown. We're not done with this script though, we'll come back to it later.
3. In your controller, call a function in your model like get_all_stud() and use that to get whatever data you need to populate the dropdown, and echo that data as json.
4. Now that your controller has returned data to the ajax function we can use it to populate the dropdown. Iterate the object and do something like `$('second_dropdown).append({<option>//your data here</option>})`

And then you'll repeat the whole thing so that the third dropdown watches for changes on the second dropdown